# Compare just time part of DateTime?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a restaurant that has `hours`. Each `Hour` object as an `open_at` and a `close_at` time. How do I compare just the time part of the DateTime in the db with the time of Time.now?

`hours.today.where("open_at <= ? AND close_at >= ?", Time.now, Time.now).any?`

edit: I tried rephrasing the question:

I have an `Hour` object `h` with an attribute `close_at` of type `Time`. How can I compare just the time part in the db with `Time.current`?

`2.1.3 :014 > h.close_at.class
     => Time 
    2.1.3 :015 > h.close_at
     => 2000-01-01 22:44:00 UTC 
    2.1.3 :016 > Time.current
     => Wed, 15 Oct 2014 17:32:27 UTC +00:00 
    2.1.3 :017 > h.close_at >= Time.current
     => false`

I want the last line to return true. (22:44 > 17:32)

Comment: In which format open_at and close_at is?

Comment: Which database? Can you change the schema?

Comment: Please use `Time.current` as `.now` is "zone-less" and should be avoided in most cases.

Comment: But which database are you using? Everyone's time and date handling functions are a little different? Again, can you change the schema so that your data types match your data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying check if there exists any hour that has been opened today and closed any time later from now:

Assuming this, you can do the required by following:

```
Hour.where(:open_at => (Time.current.midnight)..(Time.current) , :closed_at => (Time.current)..(1000.years.from_now) ).any?
```

Basically the key point is that , you can pass ranges in where clause.

And if you dont have any upper bound or lower bound , you can always use this to define the range:

```
1000.years.from_now
1000.years.ago
```

for example, any time later from now could be represented as:

```
Time.current..(1000.years.from_now)
```

Obviously you would not be making a app that needs to store time for 1000 years back and forth from now! I believe this approach should workout out in your case.

Edit:

I am sorry for misunderstanding your question. This is the workaround to the problem:

```
closing_time = h.close_at
# closing_time => 2000-01-01 22:44:00 UTC 
closing_time = Time.current.midnight + closing_time.hour.hours + closing_time.min.minutes + closing_time.sec
#this shifts the closing date_time to the current date, without affecting hours, minutes and seconds, So,
# closing_time => 2014-10-15 22:44:00 UTC 
current_time = Time.current
# current_time => Wed, 15 Oct 2014 17:32:27 UTC +00:00 
closing_time >= current_time
#=> returns true (because 22:44 > 17:32 , with other things remaining the same.)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, I added more to the question to try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare time IN SQL and if you are using MySQL you can use its TIME() function, from docs:

> Extracts the time part of the time or datetime expression expr and returns it as a string.

So you can do:

```
hours.today.where("TIME(open_at) <= ? AND TIME(close_at) >= ?", Time.now, Time.now).any?
```